# SPARK - Use RDD.foreach to Create a Dataframe and execute actions on the Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to SPARK and figuring out a better way to achieve the following scenario.
There is a database table containing 3 fields - Category, Amount, Quantity.
First I try to pull all the distinct Categories from the database.

```
 val categories:RDD[String] = df.select(CATEGORY).distinct().rdd.map(r => r(0).toString)
```

Now for each category I want to execute the Pipeline which essentially creates dataframes from each category and apply some Machine Learning.

```
 categories.foreach(executePipeline)
 def execute(category: String): Unit = {
   val dfCategory = sqlCtxt.read.jdbc(JDBC_URL,"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CATEGORY="+category)
dfCategory.show()    
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this ? Or is there any better alternative ?

Answer (score 3):

```
// You could get all your data with a single query and convert it to an rdd
val data = sqlCtxt.read.jdbc(JDBC_URL,"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME).rdd

// then group the data by category
val groupedData = data.groupBy(row => row.getAs[String]("category"))

// then you get an RDD[(String, Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])]
// and you can iterate over it and execute your pipeline
groupedData.map { case (categoryName, items) =>
  //executePipeline(categoryName, items)
}
```

Comment: `groupBy` is risky in this context - assuming each category has lots of records, this can cause an OutOfMemory error as a single, un-distributable record would hold too much data. Plus, the real issue here is that `executePipeline` can't be called on the worker-side since it uses `SQLContext` to load a DataFrame - you can't serialize that.

Comment: No. I don't load anything on the worker side, thats the point of my solution:)

Comment: About the other comment, yes groupBy can be a potentially expensive operation, but as in this case we really want to group I'd start to think about ways to circumvent it if the datasets are really that huge.

Comment: I notice a lot of people don't get this notion.

Answer (score 3):

Your code would fail on a `TaskNotSerializable` exception since you're trying to use the `SQLContext` (which isn't serializable) inside the `execute` method, which should be serialized and sent to workers to be executed on each record in the `categories` RDD.

*Assuming* you know the number of categories is *limited*, which means the list of categories isn't too large to fit in your driver memory, you should **collect the categories to driver**, and iterate over that local collection using `foreach`:

```
val categoriesRdd: RDD[String] = df.select(CATEGORY).distinct().rdd.map(r => r(0).toString)
val categories: Seq[String] = categoriesRdd.collect()
categories.foreach(executePipeline)
```

Another improvement would be reusing the dataframe that you loaded instead of performing another query, using a **filter** for each category:

```
def executePipeline(singleCategoryDf: DataFrame) { /* ... */ }

categories.foreach(cat => {
  val filtered = df.filter(col(CATEGORY) === cat)
  executePipeline(filtered)
})
```

NOTE: to make sure the re-use of `df` doesn't reload it for every execution, make sure you `cache()` it before collecting the categories.

Comment: If you collect the categories on the driver and iterate over them, it gets run sequentially, which kinda defeats the purpose of spark.

Comment: I'm assuming #Categories <<< #Records, so running on categories sequentially is much better than running sequentially on *records* (which is what a `groupBy`-based solution would do - each category creates a huge `Iterable` that can only be processed by a single task). If that assumption is wrong - indeed this isn't an optimal solution. It also seems that changing `executePipeline` to work on an `Iterable[Row]` is either hard or impossible, as OP implied it should "apply some Machine Learning" - if by that they mean MLLib, the input must be an RDD/DataFrame.

Comment: @TzachZohar , do you mean by saying Iterable[Row] , these data are iterated by Row? does not it consume more momery on spark client ?

Comment: @user3252097 that's why I'm saying you should NOT use `Iterable[Row]` (which is why I still think the other solution suggested here is NOT recommended)

Comment: @DanielB "If you collect the categories on the driver and iterate over them, it gets run sequentially, which kinda defeats the purpose of spark. "  then how should I handle this case , i am having same issue ..   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54416623/how-to-group-dataframe-year-wise-and-iterate-through-groups-and-send-each-year-d